# TextInput return type in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I was trying to update firebase database with useState that got its value from TextInput. But apparently the useState datatype changed to object instead of string. How do I go about this since firebase only takes string to update the database.

```
 const UpdateUser = async () => {
try {
  db.ref("users/" + auth.currentUser.uid).update({
    name: newuser,
  });
} catch (error) {
  alert(error);
}
setNewuser("");};
```

TextInput Code:

```
 <View>
    <Text style={styles.ProfileName}>Display Username:</Text>
    <TextInput
      placeholder={user}
      value={newuser}
      onChange={(text) => {
        setNewuser(text);
      }}
    />
    <Button onPress={UpdateUser} title="Change" />
  </View>
```

Comment: I can't see the usage of useState here but, there are 2 things you should consider. `onChange` prop returns `nativeEvent`, not the value. If you want to get the value, you should use `onChangeText` prop, or extract the value from nativeEvent. And `useState` hook returns an array with two elements, `state` and `setState` action. You should extract those with destructuring assignment `const [newUser, setNewuser] = useState("");`

Comment: Yeah onChangeText worked. The newuser is a useState, I just didn't share that part of the code. Thanks alot!
Ps. If u want u can post an answer, I would gladly approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onChangeText** is a simple prop, that gives whatever is the value of the input field on every change.**//string**

**onChange** passes an event with `{ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }`. **//object**

You can find more about the difference [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput).
Simply change it to **onChangeText** will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change **onChange** to **OnChangeText** then it will work

[refer this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext)

Comment: Hi Ajo, welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure you provide novel information (information that hasn't already been stated) when adding a new answer. This helps ensure that the community is constantly improving :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<View>
    <Text style={styles.ProfileName}>Display Username:</Text>
    <TextInput
      placeholder={user}
      value={newuser}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setNewuser(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
    <Button onPress={UpdateUser} title="Change" />
  </View>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).